# Installing mysql-server gives 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: 14.04, php, webserver, nginx, phpmyadmin

So I have this site im coding on that requires a database and is based on PHP. So for this site i installed phpmyadmin that also installed mysql-server. Before I installed phpmyadmin I didn't get a 504 message when i tried accessing it but after the install, I do. I'm running this through nginx .

Nginx error log gives me this each time I load the site but I can't make anything out of it

```
2014/08/31 21:31:31 [error] 26920#0: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock", host: "localhost"
```

If I uninstall mysql-server the problem disappears.
Iam running this site locally on my computer so timeout shouldn't be a problem.

Hopefully someone have gotten this error and can help me out.
Sorry for my english. It's not my primary language

Ubuntu 14.04.1, Nginx 1.4.6, mysql-server 5.5.38

Comment: `If I uninstall mysql-server the problem disappears.`  
So you remove the database server and everything still works? You must be using another database then, ex. postgres or sqlite.

Comment: I should have said that if I remove the database server all the content that isn't loaded from the database appears. Some basic html for the site construction and etc. But without the database the site is an empty shell. When I reinstall the database server it gives me the 504 error and that's it. Nothing more.

Comment: So your problem is really that your site can not connect to your database? What does phpmyadmin have to do with the problem?

Comment: @Jan The problem is that when I install phpmyadmin my site can't be accessed and throws a 504 at me instead. Before installing phpmyadmin I didn't gave this problem. The database isn't the problem. The standard html should work fine and just say "Couldn't connect to database" when trying to read news or etc from the db. There should be a website after the install of phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that somehow your php5-fpm / nginx config is at fault. Is there any particular reason why you use sockets instead of TCP/IP?

```
GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock
```

Probably the site loads very slow and nginx hits a timeout on php-fpm, try to set
`fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "max_execution_time=1000";`

Also, read this: http://www.nginxtips.com/504-gateway-time-out-using-nginx/